# How to reset Windows 8.1 START screen to default?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, start-screen

I would like to reset my Windows 8.1 Pro x64 START screen. It has so much stuff on it from installing software that it defeats its usefulness. I tried links such as [this one](http://www.mytechguide.org/13537/reset-windows-8-start-screen-to-default/) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 allows you to select multiple tiles then remove them.  I ended up right-clicking and selecting a tile, then clicking all other tiles, then unpinning them from start.  Took a few minutes but it's done.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
del %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms*
```

But you'll delete the related preference files, so you may want to back them up first.

More here from the [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/178667/how-to-reset-the-windows-8.x-start-screen-to-the-default-tiles/).